# Jekyll can't start correctly with error after "jekyll new [filename]"?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I've install Ruby(32bits),RubyDevkit(32 bits),gem(-v 2.4.5.1) and jekyll 3.1.2.

But when I use

```
jekyll new MyBlog
```

and "cd" into this file,I try to start the local server:

```
jekyll serve
```

But it shows there are errors in reading file as follows:

[image: screebshot]

But in fact the files which can't be found are here in the file "MyBlog".

When I write `http://localhost:4000` as url, the page in my browser is empty.

I'm confused and I don't know which step is wrong to lead to the "can't read" error.

Comment: Note that the error message shows two different paths: `E:/Jekyll/MyBlog/_layouts/...` and `E:/Jekyll/MyBlog/Jekyll/MyBlog/_layouts/...`

Comment: I changed Jekyll to version 2.4.0 and it works well! :)